# Postgres UPSERT on any constraint

Tags: postgresql, constraints, upsert, postgresql-9.5

In MySQL we can do the following on any constraint violation

```
INSERT INTO table {setters} ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {setters}
```

Is there anyway to do this in Postgres ?

```
INSERT INTO table {setters} ON CONFLICT(*) DO UPDATE {setters}
```

Note: * = Any Possible Key

Why is this an important feature?

- I want to make this code generic across multiple tables. So, I can't specify the keys as per current Postgres 9.5 syntax (Someone might argue, I could possibly store the keys on all tables and change the keys dynamically. First of all its not elegant and there is the following problem)
- While the application is live, some new unique constraints could be added at run time. So, you can't specify this in your code at Compile time
- Another Alternative is: In your app, you first try to insert and when there is a Duplicate key error, you catch catch it and try to do an update. This is really bad, as this is

  1. Not an atomic operation
  2. The latency between app server and the DB server doubles.
  3. Bulk insert is not possible

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I disagree. In MySQL  `If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY,`  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html. Also here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b51de/1 where this works on a **non primary key**

Comment: Are there any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. PostgreSQL [9.5+](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) allows you to do this, in this manner:

The `MySQL` query:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

In `PostgreSQL` becomes:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (a, b, c) values (1, 2, 10)
ON CONFLICT (a) DO UPDATE SET c = tablename.c + 1;
```

Comment: Lets say all a, b, c need to be unique and I want to make it work on any constraint violation. How do I do that?

Comment: What's the actual table definition? Is it UNIQUE(a,b,c) or UNIQUE(a), UNIQUE(b), UNIQUE(c)?

Comment: @Rahul Not sure if I get what you mean. If there are only three columns and if you want all three (in combination I assume) to be unique, a PK conflict would never need an UPDATE. And doubt if you can have this working for 'any conflict'. Does MySQL allow that?

Comment: @JimNasby UNIQUE(a), UNIQUE(b), UNIQUE(c)

Comment: @RobinsTharakan. Yes.  In MySQL  `If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY,`  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html. Also here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b51de/1 where this works on a **non primary key**

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks @Rahul. I didn't know this aspect (of MySQL) and I think that's my learning for today. To answer your question, I think postgres as of now doesn't support ambiguous constraints for this statement. i.e. It mandatorily needs a constraint / column reference to apply an alternative UPDATE clause... and thus what you're aiming for, is *not* yet possible in Postgres as of v9.5 (Confirmed by this URL: http://www.depesz.com/2015/05/10/waiting-for-9-5-add-support-for-insert-on-conflict-do-nothingupdate/ )